# Fragment onStart and onCreateActivity called after back button press

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

**Scenario:**
I have a single `Activity` in which I have `multiple fragments` and I'm `replacing` one fragment with another using `fragment transaction` and add them to `BackStack`. I am doing JSON parsing and network related task on some fragments.

**Problem:**
My problem is that after replacing the fragment when I press back button to nevigate to last fragment the `onStart` and `onActivityCreated` methods called again. My code in these events execute each time I `navigate` to that `fragment` by using `back button`

**But**
Any value in `EditText` remain same in even after `replacing` the fragment and coming back to it using back button.

Why `onStart` and `onActivityCreated` executed each time?
Is there any method where I can put my code which do not execute after coming back to fragment?

**UPDATE**
Basically I want to set a button text once fragment is created. User can change that text. but when I return back to that fragment the users value change with the default text which I set on fragment creation time.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can put your code to run only one time at fragment creation in `onCreate()` of fragment..

**onCreate()**

The system calls this when creating the fragment. Within your implementation, you should initialize essential components of the fragment that you want to retain when the fragment is paused or stopped, then resumed.

See the life cycle of fragment.[image]

You can also get more details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: in which method you have set the button text ?